# How to use route names as a global variable on returns

Tags: go

I use echo-labstack, a framework for Go, and I try to use routes.Name as a global variable in my API.

```
e.GET("/", Sources.Login).Name = "LOGIN"

func Login(c echo.Context) error {
    return c.Render(http.StatusOK, "login.html", "OK")
}
```

On my method, I would like to use my route.Name directly on the return so I don't have to put my URL hard like this :

```
func Login(c echo.Context) error {
    return c.Render(http.StatusOK, LOGIN, "OK")
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How can i use "LOGIN" as variable in my return like this
`return c.Render(http.StatusOK, LOGIN, "OK")`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you could just use constants. Something like this:

```
type MyRoute string    
const LOGIN MyRoute = "login"
func (mr MyRoute) Name() string {
    return strings.ToUpper(mr)
}

func (mr MyRoute) HTML() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s.html", mr)
}
e.GET("/", Sources.Login).Name = LOGIN.Name()

func Login(c echo.Context) error {
    return c.Render(http.StatusOK, LOGIN.HTML(), "OK")
}
```

Please consider this code has not been tested.

Comment: I would just like to be able to create global variables of the links of my routes, and be able to use them on my API, for example instead of returning `c.Render(http.StatusOK, "login.html", "OK")`, having return `c.Render(http.StatusOK, ROUTES, "OK")`

Comment: in my example you can just define constants for your routes and use them. The constants can be in a separate package, so they will be usable globally.

Comment: Yeah
Thank you very much, I just tested the code it works pretty well